# Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni Android studio logs

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-logcat

I am trying to run a simple app that extracts html from a page and displays it in the logs.

Here is the Java code:

```
 package com.example.khkr.jsondemo;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            URL url;
            String result = "";

            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data!=-1)
                {
                    char current = (char)data;                    result+=current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String weatherInfo =  jsonObject.getString("weather");
                Log.i("Weather content",weatherInfo);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't see any errors in the code , but when I try to run the app, I get the following Logs which never make sense to me. Here are the logs:

https://gist.github.com/khkr/d96396ff6f8e34b3e9a430a805b735a7